# Why is erdantic now showing one to many / list relationships?

Tags: pydantic, erd, documentation-generation

When using erdantic with pydantic model, the one to many relationships are not rendered properly

As shown below the erdantic examples work as expected, however the simple example I have shown is not rendered correctly. I can't see the difference between the A class I have written and the party example. Any help much appreciated!

```
import erdantic as erd
from erdantic.examples.pydantic import Party

# Easy one-liner
erd.draw(Party, out="diagram.png")


class B(BaseModel):
    """
    B Class
    """

    id: str


class A(BaseModel):
    """
    A Class
    """

    list_b: List[B]


erd.draw(A, out="A.jpg")
```

A.jpg
[A.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRfe1.jpg)

diagram.jpg
[diagram.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvsm.png)